# Unable to find encoder for Decimal type stored in a DataSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Folks-

I am a complete Spark newb and have been trying to get the code below to work in `spark-shell` for the past day. I took the time to review the docs and tried to Google the problem but, I am running out of ideas.

Below is the code:

```
import spark.implicits._
val opts = Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:netezza://netezza:5480/test_schema",
    "user" -> "user",
    "password" -> "password",
    "dbtable" -> "test_messages",
    "numPartitions" -> "48"
)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val site = sqlContext
  .read()
  .format("com.ibm.spark.netezza")
  .options(opts)
  .load()
  .select("az","range","time")
  .where("id == 34000007")
```

`site.printSchema()` illustrates all columns are of type `decimal`

```
val calcs = ama.agg(
    min("az"), (max("az")-min("az")).divide(100),
    min("range"), (max("range")-min("range")).divide(100),
    min("time"), (max("time")-min("time")).divide(100)
).collect()(0)
```

`calcs.printSchema()` illustrates all columns are of type `decimal`

Everything works as expected until this line. I thought that by `import spark.implicits._` this would give me access to the `Encoder` that was required but, that is not the case.

```
val newSite = site.map( r => r.getDecimal(0).subtract(calcs.getDecimal(0)) )
```

Every post that I have reviewed talks about importing `implicits` but, this has not helped.  I am using Spark 2.0.2.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply no `Encoder` for `Decimal` in `spark.implicits`. You can provide it either explicitly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders 

val dt = DecimalType(38, 0)
val df = Seq((1, 2)).toDF("x", "y").select($"x".cast(dt), $"y".cast(dt))

df.map(r => r.getDecimal(0).subtract(r.getDecimal(1)))(Encoders.DECIMAL).first
```

```
java.math.BigDecimal = -1.000000000000000000
```

or `implicitly`:

```
implicit val decimalEncoder = Encoders.DECIMAL

df.map(r => r.getDecimal(0).subtract(r.getDecimal(1))).first
```

```
java.math.BigDecimal = -1.000000000000000000
```

That being said it could be a better idea to use `DataFrames` all the way for example:

```
site.select($"az" - calcs.getDecimal(0))
```

or

```
site.select($"az" - calcs.getAs[java.math.BigDecimal]("min(az)"))
```